# List log stream in each aws log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to list log streams in each of the aws log groups? I need to get the lists of all log streams in every log group and check the Last event time for cleanup purposes.

Best Regards,
Ell

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [describe-log-streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-streams.html).

For example: `aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name my-logs`

You can first use [`describe-log-groups`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-groups.html) to get a list of your log groups.